# Fixing leaking Sloan Royal Flushometer

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, plumbing-fixture, bathroom-fixtures

I've got a Sloan Royal Flushometer that is leaking after some flushes. The leak comes from both sides of the cover (see pictures). This happened once, years ago, and I fixed it by simply replacing the diaphragm so I tried the same this time with replacement kit A-1042-A. The leaking is less than it was but I can't stop it completely. Any ideas on how to troubleshoot or resolve?

[image: Leak spot number 1]
[image: Leak spot number 2]